# Optimizing app.yaml

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Concerning response time, instance hours and caching efficiency which one of the following configurations is most efficient for Google App Engine on Python 2.7:

**Config 1**

App.yaml:

```
handlers:

- url: /db/script/.*
  script: db/script/crud.app
  secure: always

- url: /db/state/.*
  script: db/state/crud.app
  secure: always

- url: /db/var/.*
  script: db/var/crud.app
  secure: always
```

**Or Config 2**

App.yaml:

```
handlers:

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
```

With main.py:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/db/script/.*', db.Script.Crud),
    ('/db/state/.*', db.State.Crud),
    ('/db/var/.*', db.Var.Crud)
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding performance (response time, instance hours), take a look here:

- [Is there a performance gain from defining routes in app.yaml versus one large mapping in a WSGIApplication in AppEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025921/is-there-a-performance-gain-from-defining-routes-in-app-yaml-versus-one-large-ma)

Regarding caching, it depends on what kind of caching you are thinking of:

- Datastore caching happens automatically when you use NDB so the routing setup should not matter.
- Browser caching depends on the web framework you are using (e.g. webapp2). You can also define specific routes for [static files](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Handlers).
- Memcached is handled in your code and is thus not dependent on your routing setup.