# default properties for all urls in app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

My app.yaml file has many different url handlers, but there are some properties that must be in every one of them. For instance, a `secure: always` property. How can I make this a default property and avoid having to manually add this to every handler?

```
handlers:
- url: /api/.+
  script: backend.api.app
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  static_files: static/pages/build/index.html
  upload: static/pages/build/index.html
  secure: always
```

I am worried that I will add a url and forget to copy all of my default properties into it.

Note:
I use Grunt, so if it is impossible to do this though Google App Engine a solution that parses the YAML file and adds properties could work

Comment: Why the downvote whoever you are? Is there something I could do to ask better questions in the future?

Comment: Downvote makes no sense, hence, upvoting to compensate.

Comment: Thank you @Alex Martelli

Comment: Why not use single entry point and manage routes on python side? And SSL for static files does not seems to be so important.

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi I considered that, but somehow assumed that it would be faster to manage routes in app.yaml than python-side. Am I wrong? Also, I thought that SSL for static files would help prevent an attacker from modifying their content. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't think that you're going to feel the difference in performance. Anyway, if you use something like `grunt` or `gulp` – I'm sure you can write your own solution and share it with public.

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi You were correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025921/is-there-a-performance-gain-from-defining-routes-in-app-yaml-versus-one-large-ma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no configurable defaults for handlers other than those mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig).

But you can write a simple script to load your `app.yaml` file and check that all your handlers have whichever common configurations you desire ;)

Comment: Specifically, use PyYAML -- http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML -- to parse a YAML file into Python data structures in memory, alter those data structures as you require, then use PyYAML again to emit them as YAML -- much like you'd do for other serialization formats such as JSON or XML (with different parser-and-emitter modules in each case of course).